# How to have footer in first page? (Table of contents is also in the first page)

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I have footer in my article file, but the footer does not show in the first page.
The Table of Contents is in the first page too, there is a page number in the bottom of the page, but I do not need the page number, so i use below

```
\tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

The number is gone, but the footer is still not there.
If I do not use \thispagestyle{empty} the footer still not there

```
\tableofcontents
```

How to have the footer in the first page?(now it shows every page except the first page)

Comment: Please add a small minimal working example. At the moment I can't understand your issue.

Comment: With \thispagestyle{empty} you erase the heading and footer for this one page. So it cannot show a footer. If you instead use \pagestyle{...} and insert the pagestyle you used to define your footer it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not posted a MWE I don't know what package you used to define your footer, so I used `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` to create one to show you how it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}                         % clears the previous formatting of header and foot
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % erases the rule under the header
\cfoot{my own footer}              % here you can define your footer 

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}                  
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Section 1}
\newpage
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

In your first example you used `\thispagestyle{empty}` to get rid of the number, but this just deleted the whole header and footer. Therefore you have to leave that command out. But you still have to include the command `\pagestyle{fancy}` so that it actually uses your own footer you defined earlier. Because you said it shows on all the other pages, my guess would be that you used `\pagestyle{fancy}` on a page after your table of contents.

Because you said "my article file", I assume you mean that your documentclass is article. The solution might be different for other classes, for example report.